# HOWTO Update oracle's JVM?

Tags: oracle, jvm

I'm trying to solve [problem with xml validation in oracle jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795866/validating-xml-document-in-oracles-java-source)

And found another examples of doing that:

SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = 
    SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(
    new Source[] {new StreamSource("contacts.xsd")}));

SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
reader.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());
reader.parse(new InputSource("document.xml"));
```

But it seems to me that this example expecting to use newer version of Java therefore some methods and classes are absent in my JVM. They are SchemaFactory class and setSchema method of SAXParserFactory class. I want to update, but I didn't found on oracle's tech support forums that it is posssible at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the JVM that runs inside Oracle, it is directly tied to the version of Oracle that is in use.  The only way to get a newer JVM is to upgrade Oracle.  Although perhaps if enough people submit enhancement requests they will backport a newer JVM to older versions.